# Creating a yellow-colored image of noise with Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I've managed to create red, green and blue noise in Matlab using `imagesc(cat(3,zeros(10,20),rand(10,20),zeros(10,20)))`. I'm now trying to combine individual colors to make yellow. But when I add multiple `rand`'s together in the `cat`, both those colors appear. How can I fix that?

Comment: You got me really startled there - usually `somecolor` noise refers to frequency components of a distribution (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colors_of_noise) and I never heard of "yellow noise" before...

Comment: @TobiasKienzler I had the same thought as well, but (as a hint to future readers) the use of `imagesc` gave away that we are dealing with images rather than sounds or distributions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an intuitive way to do it:

```
Noise = rand(10,20);
```

One color example:

```
imagesc(cat(3,zeros(10,20),Noise,zeros(10,20)))
```

Two color example:

```
imagesc(cat(3,zeros(10,20),Noise,Noise))
```

This is a little easier to apply than the solution by @Luis if you want color 1 and 3 to have noise rather than only 2 adjacent colors. Also I don't know if it makes sense, but it allows you to get different colors by scaling the noise with a constant.

Comment: Thank you, I'll accept this as an answer because it is the most dynamic

Answer (score 6):

For yellow, use the same values in the R and G components:

```
imagesc(cat(3,repmat(rand(10,20),[1,1,2]),zeros(10,20)))
```